# What is the purpose of boost::fusion?

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, boost-fusion

Ive spent the day reading notes and watching a video on boost::fusion and I really don't get some aspects to it.

Take for example, the `boost::fusion::has_key<S>` function. What is the purpose of having this in boost::fusion? Is the idea that we just try and move as much programming as possible to happen at compile-time? So pretty much any `boost::fusion` function is the same as the run-time version, except it now evaluates at compile time? (and we assume doing more at compile-time is good?).

Related to boost::fusion, i'm also a bit confused why metafunctions always return types. Why is this?

Comment: I'd rather discover an error at compile time than at run-time.

Comment: Is an STL for tuples. If you map classes to tuples, you can use it for compile-time reflection.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to look at boost::fusion is to think of it as "poor man introspection" library. The original motivation for boost::fusion comes from the direction of boost::spirit parser/generator framework, in particular the need to support what is called "parser attributes".

Imagine, you've got a CSV string to parse:

> aaaa, 1.1

The type, this string parses into, can be described as "tuple of string and double". We can define such tuples in "plain" C++, either with old school structs (`struct { string a; double b; }` or newer `tuple<string, double>`). The only thing we miss is some sort of adapter, which will allow to pass tuples (and some other types) of arbitrary composition to a unified parser interface and expect it to make sense of it without passing any out of band information (such as string parsing templates used by scanf).

That's where boost::fusion comes into play. The most straightforward way to construct a "fusion sequence" is to adapt a normal struct:

```
struct a {
    string s;
    double d;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(a, (string, s)(double, d))
```

The "ADAPT_STRUCT" macro adds the necessary information for parser framework (in this example) to be able to "iterate" over members of `struct a` to the tune of the following questions:

1. I just parsed a string. Can I assign it to first member of `struct a`?
2. I just parsed a double. Can I assign it to second member of `struct a`?
3. Are there any other members in `struct a` or should I stop parsing?

Obviously, this basic example can be further extended (and boost::fusion supplies the capability) to address much more complex cases:

1. Variants - let's say parser can encounter either sting or double and wants to assign it to the right member of `struct a`. `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_STRUCT` comes to the rescue (now our parser can ask questions like "which member of `struct a` is of type double?").
2. Transformations - our parser can be designed to accept certain types as parameters but the rest of the programs had changed quite a bit. Yet, fusion metafunctions can be conveniently used to adapt new types to old realities (or vice versa).

The rest of boost::fusion functionality naturally follows from the above basics. fusion really shines when there's a need for conversion (in either direction) of "loose IO data" to strongly typed/structured data C++ programs operate upon (if efficiency is of concern). It is the enabling factor behind spirit::qi and spirit::karma being such an efficient (probably the fastest) I/O frameworks .

Answer (score 4):

Fusion is there as a bridge between compile-time and run-time containers and algorithms. You may or may not want to move some of your processing to compile-time, but if you do want to then Fusion might help. I don't think it has a specific manifesto to move as much as possible to compile-time, although I may be wrong.

Meta-functions return types because template meta-programming wasn't invented on purpose. It was discovered more-or-less by accident that C++ templates can be used as a compile-time programming language. A meta-function is a mapping from template arguments to instantiations of a template. As of C++03 there were are two kinds of template (class- and function-), therefore a meta-function has to "return" either a class or a function. Classes are more useful than functions, since you can put values etc. in their static data members.

C++11 adds another kind of template (for typedefs), but that is kind of irrelevant to meta-programming. More importantly for compile-time programming, C++11 adds `constexpr` functions. They're properly designed for the purpose and they return values just like normal functions. Of course, their input is not a type, so they can't be mappings from types to something else in the way that templates can. So in that sense they lack the "meta-" part of meta-programming. They're "just" compile-time evaluation of normal C++ functions, not meta-functions.